# C programming variable in an other variable

Tags: c, sockets, variables

i have a problem, i would need to send some data to a socket, the data is stored in an char variable (lets call it variable A), but some things in this data are changing, is it possible to insert another variable (varaible B) in this variable and send variable A with the changes made by variable B?

variable B:

```
char B[] = "inserted by the user"
```

variable A:

```
char A[] = "soemthing '%Variable B' something else"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Have you looked into `snprintf`?

Comment: As in `s*printf`? Or do you mean it should change automatically with the variable?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
char * A = malloc(strlen(B) + 40); /* You can tot up the additional bit here for 
                                    the rest of A including the null */
sprintf(A, "something '%s' something else", B);
```

Comment: Why put the limitation in when the amount of space can be computed.

Comment: Future maintainer decides to add a longer phrase but doesn't realize to change the `malloc` statement.  Now you have UB that is also a security hole on your hands.  `snprintf` should always be preferred.

Comment: Either the developer should know better, or the code review is not working, nor is testing. With `snprintf` without checking the return value will always work but give the wrong result on occasions. To check you need to compute the number of bytes - read the manual page (quote: "Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed")